# UIMangedDocument Context is nil

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to learn how to use Core Data and UIManagedDocuments. First I create/open the document:

```
NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProjectSSBDB"];

document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) 
{
     [document openWithCompletionHandler: ^(BOOL success) 
     {
         if (success) [ProjectSSViewController documentIsReady];
         if (!success) NSLog(@"Couldn't open document at %@", url);
      }];
 } 
 else 
 {
    [document saveToURL:url forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success) 
            {
               NSLog(@"Returned %d", success);
               if (success) [ProjectSSViewController documentIsReady];
               if (!success) NSLog(@"Couldn't create document at %@", url);
             }];
 }
```

Then, once the document is created and opened successfully, I do this:

```
 if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateNormal) 
   {

            NSManagedObjectContext *context = [document managedObjectContext];

            Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    }
```

It seems like the last line here is the one giving me the error: **'+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Exercise''**

I have definitely created a data model that has an 'Exercise' entity. From the reading I've done it could be something to do with the way different threads interact with the context? But I'm not really sure, any guidance would be great!

Comment: Can you show me your `managedObjectContext` method ?

Comment: Have you solved that issue ? If yes then Accept the Answer.

Answer (score 0):

> +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Exercise'

There are only 3 Possibilities :

1. Misspelling the entity name e.g. Exercises instead of Exercise.
2. Having a nil managed object context
3. Having no or the wrong managed object model loaded.

Most Probability in your Case is 2nd one ( may be your managed object context is Nil ).

Comment: The `managedObjectContext` method is just the one for the property on `UIManagedDocument`. Also does the same thing if I do `document.managedObjectContext`.

Comment: @rheotron : Have you tried *deleting the app from the simulator*, *clean* and *Re-build* ?

Comment: @rheotron: Check if your `managedObjectContext` is returning *NULL* or not ?

Comment: Yeah it's returning nil. I imagine they're the same.

Comment: @rheotron : That's the Problem itself.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that's the problem, but what reasons would there be for a `UIManagedDocument` retuning nil?

Comment: It's not my method. It's a property of the `UIManagedDocument` class as outlined [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIManagedDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIManagedDocument/managedObjectContext) in the documentation.

Comment: @rheotron : Download any Core data tutorial project and check it's `AppDelegate.m` file. You'll get some methods named `managedObjectContext`,`managedObjectModel`,`persistentStoreCoordinator`. You need to add those methods in your Project that'll help you to create new instance of your `managedObjectContext` whenever you needed.